Sigma field generated by gaussian random variable
Say $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then $X$ takes values in the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. Now is it possible to say what $\sigma(X)$ will be exactly? We have $\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B), \;\;\forall \;\; B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$, but we do not know what set of values $\omega \in \Omega$ that $X^{-1}(B)$ will map to, do we? If $X(\omega) = \omega$ and $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, am I correct in saying that $\sigma(X) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?
Can someone give an example where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ defined on the same $\Omega$ where $\sigma(X)  \neq \sigma(Y)$?
Thanks!

This answer is based on the first response on @user469053. Please tell me if it is correct.
Let $A\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{P})$, with $A(\omega) = \omega$. Define $X,Y: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ on the product space $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2),\mathbb{P}\otimes\mathbb{P})$ by $X\big( ( \omega_1, \omega_2) \big) = A( \omega_1)  = \omega_1$ and $Y\big( ( \omega_1, \omega_2) \big) = A( \omega_2) = \omega_2$. We have $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Now note that $X$ is constant on vertical lines, that is, given an observed value $X = \omega_1 = a$ we now that it must have come from
\begin{equation*}
    (\omega_1, \omega_2) \in \bigcup_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}} \{ (a, \omega)\}.
\end{equation*}
In other words
\begin{equation*}
    \bigcup_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}} \{ (a, \omega)\} \in \sigma(X),
\end{equation*}
however, note now that $Y$ is constant on horizontal values. Given an observed value $Y = \omega_2 = b$ we won't know from which $\omega_1$ we got this value, and more specifically we will not know if $\omega_1 = a$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
    \bigcup_{\omega \in \mathbb{R}} \{ (a, \omega)\} \notin \sigma(Y) \implies \sigma(X) \neq \sigma(Y).
\end{equation*}

$\sigma(X)=\sigma(Y)$ iff $X$ is measurable function of $Y$ and conversely. So any independent gaussian variables $X$ and $Y$ are such that $\sigma(X)\neq\sigma(Y)$.

I don't really understand. If I have $X(\omega) = \omega$ and $Y(\omega) = \omega$ with $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, isn't $\sigma(X) = \sigma(Y) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$? $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Yes. But here you chose equal random variables, so not independent at all.

Ok, got you. So how can I choose independent random variables defined on the same $\Omega$ and see that $\sigma(X) \neq \sigma(Y)$. Is there an explicit example?

@Will's comment is correct. I changed examples midstream and didn't update everything. I also had $A$ denoting two separate things. It was too late to edit, so I scrapped it.

Let $A\sim N(0,1)$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$. Define $X,Y:\Omega\times\Omega$ on the product space $(\Omega\times \Omega,\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}\otimes \mathbb{P})$ by $X((\omega_1,\omega_2))=A(\omega_1)$ and $Y((\omega_1,\omega_2))=A(\omega_2).$  For any subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $(x,y)\in \Omega\times \Omega$ satisfies $X(x,y)\in C$ iff $X(x,y)=A(x)\in C$. So $$X^{-1}(C)=A^{-1}(C)\times \Omega.$$  Similarly, $Y^{-1}(C)=\Omega\times A^{-1}(C).$$

@user469053 your example was very interesting, maybe that would deserve its own answer?

@user469053 But my statement for your set-up that $\bigcup_{\omega \in \Omega}{(\omega_1, \omega) } \in \sigma(X)$ while, $\bigcup_{\omega \in \Omega}{(\omega_1, \omega) } \notin \sigma(Y)$, is true, no?

@Bigggie My intention was to have $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{A}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\sigma(A)=\mathcal{A}$. In this case, the answer to your question is yes, for a fixed $\omega_1$.

Let's start with a general construction of how to construct independent copies of random variables. Let $A,B$ be random variables on (possibly different) probability spaces $(\Omega_0,\mathcal{A}_0,\mathbb{P}_0)$ and $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1,\mathbb{P}_1)$, respectively.  Define $X,Y$ on the product space $(\Omega_0\times \Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_0\otimes \mathcal{B}_1,\mathbb{P}_0\otimes \mathbb{P}_1$ by $$X(x,y)=A(x)$$ and $$Y(x,y)=B(y).$$
For a measurable subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and $(x,y)\in \Omega_0\times \Omega_1$, $X(x,y)\in C$ iff $A(x)\in C$, so $$X^{-1}(C)=A^{-1}(C)\times \Omega_1.$$  Note that by the definition of the product measure,  $$\mathbb{P}_0\otimes\mathbb{P}_1(A^{-1}(C)\times \Omega_1)=\mathbb{P}_0(A^{-1}(C))\cdot \mathbb{P}_1(\Omega_1)=\mathbb{P}_0(A^{-1}(C)).$$  This shows that $A,X$ have the same distribution and $$\sigma(X)=\{C\times \Omega_1:C\in \sigma(A)\}.$$  Here we remark that the idea is that, since $X$ doesn't depend on $y$, $X$ is constant on "vertical lines" (imagining $\Omega_0\times \Omega_1$ as a plane). Since $X$ is constant on vertical lines, if the preimage $X^{-1}(C)$ contains a point $(x,y)$, it must contain the entire "vertical line" that goes through $x$. That is, for a fixed $x\in \Omega_0$, $X^{-1}(C)$ either contains $(x,y)$ for all $y$ for for none of them.
Similarly, $$Y^{-1}(C)=B^{-1}(C)=\Omega_0\times B^{-1}(C),$$ $B,Y$ have the same distribution, and $$\sigma(Y)=\{\Omega_0\times C:C\in\sigma(B)\}.$$
Last, one can easily check in a manner similar to the preceding arguments that for measurable subsets $C,D$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and $(x,y)\in \Omega_0\times \Omega_1$, $$(X(x,y),Y(x,y))\in C\times D$$ iff $x\in A^{-1}(C)$ and $y\in B^{-1}(D)$. So $$\{(x,y)\in \Omega_0\times \Omega_1:(X(x,y),Y(x,y))\in C\times D\}=A^{-1}(C)\times B^{-1}(D).$$  Then $$\mathbb{P}_0\otimes \mathbb{P}_1((X,Y)\in C\times D)=\mathbb{P}_0\otimes \mathbb{P}_1(A^{-1}(C)\times B^{-1}(D))=\mathbb{P}_0(A\in C)\mathbb{P}_1(B\in D)=\mathbb{P}_0(X\in C)\mathbb{P}_1(Y\in D).$$  So $X,Y$ are independent.
If $X$ is non-constant, $\sigma(X)$ contains some $C$ with $\varnothing\subsetneq C\subsetneq \Omega_0$. Then $C\otimes \Omega_1\in \sigma(X)\setminus \sigma(Y)$.
